# Meteor JS 1.3 errors loading isopacket "ddp"

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to get into MeteorJS and learn how it works, however after installing a fresh copy of MeteorJS 1.3 and creating a project, I am always met with the error below.
I've been searching through Google for a while now and I can't come across anyone with the same problem, which is odd because this is a completely fresh installation.

```
Errors prevented isopacket load:

While loading isopacket `ddp`:
module.js:338:15: Cannot find module './_baseClone'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\node_modules\lodash\clone.js:1:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:314:38)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\node_modules\babel-template\lib\index.js:84:43)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\ddp\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs\lib\index.js:525:46)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Module.Mp.load (C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\reify\node\runtime.js:16:23)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object._.extend.Npm.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1570:22)
at Object.require (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1547:11)
at Package (packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:17:1)
at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1
at packages/babel-compiler/babel-compiler.js:356:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You on Windows 7 or 10 I presume?

I think they broke it with their latest v1.3.3 update today. I am having the exact same issues off brand new installs. Things used to work in v1.3.2 and I am unsure on how to fix this for v1.3.3 yet.

Theoretically though, you can try running it off an older build. Try this.

```
meteor create myApp --release 1.3.2.4
cd myApp
meteor
```

It will probably take a really long time to initially create the app, but when it finally finishes it should work. Just don't do "meteor update" on it for now.

Comment: I'm actually on Windows 8.1. I tried creating my project using the 1.3.2_4 version, but I've been sitting here for 2 hours straight on "Downloading meteor-tool@1.3.2_4...". Should it really take this long?  
Edit: I restarted it and it finished in a couple of minutes, wow.

Comment: Alright it finished setting up the project and I ran it, which works fine now without any errors popping up. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Ya, the really long time seems to be due to a CDN issue they are currently having.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6960